# CodePipeline does not upload buildspec artifacts like CodeBuild does

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have the following excerpt from a buildspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
  build:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - cd e2e
      - npm install
  post_build:
    commands:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true npm run e2e:$APP_MODULE
    finally:
      - FILENAME="${APP_MODULE}_out.json"
      - echo ${FILENAME}
      - mv .nyc_output/out.json ${FILENAME}
artifacts:
  base-directory: e2e
  files:
    - '${FILENAME}'
  secondary-artifacts:
    videos:
      base-directory: e2e/cypress/videos
      files: 
        - '**/*'
```

When I run this CodeBuild stand alone, both the primary and secondary artifacts are uploaded to S3.

```
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Expanding base directory path: e2e
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Expanding e2e
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Expanding file paths for base directory e2e
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Expanding ${FILENAME}
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Expanded to layout_out.json
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Found 1 file(s)
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Preparing to copy secondary artifacts videos
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Expanding base directory path: e2e/cypress/videos
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Expanding e2e/cypress/videos
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Expanding file paths for base directory e2e/cypress/videos
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Expanding **/*
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:18 Found 4 file(s)
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:18:19 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
```

When run through CodePipeline, only the secondary artifacts are uploaded!

```
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:33:00 Uploading S3 cache...
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:53 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:53 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:53 Preparing to copy secondary artifacts videos
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:53 Expanding base directory path: e2e/cypress/videos
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:53 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:53 Expanding e2e/cypress/videos
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:53 Expanding file paths for base directory e2e/cypress/videos
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:53 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:53 Expanding **/*
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:53 Found 4 file(s)
[Container] 2020/08/16 15:34:54 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
```

FYI CodePipeline is configured to run parallel build actions running the same CodeBuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround: Specify both artifacts as secondary in the CodeBuild config and the buildspec.

```
artifacts:
  secondary-artifacts:
    artifact1:
      base-directory: $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      files:
        - source1_file
    artifact2:
      base-directory: $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_source2
      files:
        - source2_file
```

The names need to match those in the CodeBuild's *Artifacts* configuration - use the *Add Artifact* button to add further secondary artifacts.

Comment: The hint of `the name of Project's Artifacts` really helps.